# How to make css styles in the document body only specific to a div

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-docs

On a basic level, we have:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="Template"></div>
      <div id="Content">
         <style>h1... h2....</style>
         <h1></h1><p></p>.... (Content)
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How do i get the style tag within 'Content', to only apply to the Content div, and not the whole page, but I can't alter the content of the style tag (ie adding #Content before each declaration wont work)

We're pulling content in from Google Docs, and want to use their stylesheet on the document to style the content, without destroying the template around the document.

So far - iFrame seems like the only option, I just don't want the container to be fixed height...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can make your style rules for your template be more specific than the Google rules so that your template always uses your rules and not Google's.

Comment: This actually seems to be the best way of going about it with each of the other answers making more issues, this just means I have to be much more diligent in the template styling.

Comment: made easier by the !importance declaration (see link below).

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery to resize the `iframe` if it's less of a headache for you:

http://www.phinesolutions.com/use-jquery-to-adjust-the-iframe-height.html

Answer (score 1):

Does the importance rule solve this? http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/f/blcssfaqimportn.htm

Answer (score 0):

style tags *should* only be in the head section.

To get the styles within it to only apply to stuff in the "Content" tag, prefix your selectors with:

```
#Content h1{
  /*only styles for h1 tags inside the Content element*/
}
#Content p{
  /*only styles for p tags inside the Content element*/
}
```

PS although the style tag *should* be in the head, most browsers will let you place them anywhere.  The advantage to putting it in the head is that it can be parsed and be ready to apply before you render any DOM elements that might match it... thus avoid the "FOUC" (Flash Of Unstyled Content)

Comment: I can't alter the content of the style tag as it's being pulled direct from Google Docs. Looking at maybe a regex to add #Content before each line, hoping for a better resolution...

Comment: He said that he is pulling this page in from Google Docs and the snippet shown is how the page is styled. I would think he is looking for more an automated or abstracted way to deal with this scenario, rather than extracting every single style element and appending ids to everything....

Comment: you could use JavaScript to "move" it into the head (won't quite solve the issue, but its feasible.  The problem is (regardless) if the styles aren't *scoped* to the tags inside the `"Content"` element, it will still be very hard to style.  Of course, you could add your own style tag in the head with the styles you want to force an override (use very specific selectors) even with the other style tag being loaded mid-document)